# Android: How to implement Interface Class in ActivityClass and Class

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, android-asynctask

My project have 1 activity class, 1 interface class and 2 classes. One class is extends with AsyncTask.

**Activity Class**

```
public class ActivityClass extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskListener {
   TaskListener listener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Call asyncTask class
        Server myServer = new Server(listener);
        myServer.execute(request);
   }

   @Override
   public void taskComplete(boolean status) {
       //Task complete
   }
}
```

**Interface Class**

```
public interface TaskListener {
    public void taskComplete(boolean status);
}
```

**AsyncTask Class**

```
public class Server extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void> {
   TaskListener listener;

   public Server(TaskListener l) {
        this.listener = l;
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
        ...........
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       listener.taskComplete(success);
   }
}
```

**Other Class**

```
public class Operation extends TaskListener {

}
```

I've got an error in `Other Class` (`No interface expected here`). I'm confused how can I implement Interface class in the both class.

Comment: For interface you should use "implements" key word instead "extends".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Operation extends TaskListener {}
```

Because extends expects a class, not an interface. Interface should be used with implements. Change to:

```
public class Operation implements TaskListener {}
```